# How to handle GZIP, Deflate accept encoding in Mule

Tags: mule, gzip, anypoint-studio, deflate, http-accept-encoding

How does mule handle GZIP, Deflate Accept Encoding Headers?

Is it automatic or do we need to use the GZIP Compress connector or do we need to do something else when the application receives this as a header?

I am using Mule 3.8.1 and Anypoint Studio 6.1.

Thanks